# pkexec shows in command line instead of GUI pop-up

Tags: authentication, d-bus, pop-os, polkit, pkexec

I just hopped to Pop!_os yesterday and `pkexec` executes in terminal.
It also ran into the error:

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it next time

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I forgot to install a GUI `polkit` client. I installed `mate-polkit` and it works fine now!